# Java threads were broken

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I tried to run several threads like the following:

```
Thread threadWinter = new Thread(() -> IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach((n) -> System.out.println("Winter")));
Thread threadSpring = new Thread(() -> IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach((n) -> System.out.println("Spring")));
Thread threadSummer = new Thread(() -> IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach((n) -> System.out.println("Summer")));
Thread threadAutumn = new Thread(() -> IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach((n) -> System.out.println("Autumn")));
threadWinter.start();
threadSpring.start();
threadSummer.start();
threadAutumn.start();
```

And each run output looks like following:

```
Spring
Spring
Spring
Summer
Summer
Summer
Winter
Winter
Winter
Autumn
Autumn
Autumn
```

So, threads output order could be different, but it does not mixed together. It looks wrong. What reason could be for this behavior and how to fix it (get rows in random order)?

Comment: `System.out` is a **buffered** `PrintStream`. What do you mean "fix it"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Thank you! You mean, that buffering lead to all rows at once? I would prefer the lines to be printed randomly

Comment: Re, "It looks wrong." To you, maybe, but it _isn't_ wrong. When you perform different activities in different, unsynchronized threads, then you are effectively saying, "I don't care about the order in which they happen." If you _need_ certain things to happen in a certain order, then the best way to do it is to do all of those things in the same single thread.

Comment: Your threads do next-to-nothing independently.  The IO stream has it's own internal lock and a loop to 4 is just insignificant.

Comment: *"How to get it in random order"* - The order of execution is **completely** in the hands of the OS scheduler. If it thinks its faster to execute something sequentially, because it is small, then it will do so. Do not expect any order from multi-threaded code like this, including expecting to get something *"random"*.

Comment: @besmirched - I do not mean random in mathematical meaning. I tried to watch context switching between threads. And I didn't succeed

Comment: @MartinJames - Thank you. I unsuccessfully tried loop to 100, too

Comment: Um...computers are really fast.  Try 100,000,000, printing every 25,000,000.

Comment: @MartinJames - Thank you. 10,000 has worked for me. However, for some people (@AndrewTobilko answer) - 3 were enough

Answer (score 3):

`System.out` is buffer-based, it won't flush the stream on every message.

To mess it up, try to flush it manually.

```
Thread threadWinter = new Thread(() -> IntStream.range(1, 4)
    .forEach((n) -> {
        System.out.println("Winter"); 
        System.out.flush();
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you - Unfortunately it doesn't help (+ I use `range(1, 100)`)

Comment: @Loom did you add flush for all the threads? Before posting, I could mess it up even with the range [1-3]

Comment: @Loom note that it's not something to expect a well-defined behaviour from. So you may want to run the snippet multiple times :)

Comment: The `PrintStream` `System.out` is configured to automatically `flush()`, and as the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) notes *this means that the `flush` method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the `println` methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte (`'\n'`) is written.*

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - 10 000 worked for me. And there was continually pieces of ~500 lines of the same season

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the javadoc says "Optionally, a PrintStream **can** be created so as to flush automatically", but I didn't find "`System.out` is configured to automatically flush()"...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It's a global. And it flushes on newline. [Line 1144](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l1144): `setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));` uses [`PrintStream(OutputStream, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)) (and the `boolean` is `true`). Of note, without that, you would never get any output from `System.out` without an explicit `flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my observations I would say printing just 4 items in each thread is not enough to keep the thread printing long enough for the other threads to start. Try printing like a hundred rows in each thread.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately It doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add multiple threads printing each message. `System.out` is buffered and a global, also of note is that `println()` includes an *implicit* `flush()`. I would start with a simple class to print the message. Something like,

```
static class MessagePrinter implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public MessagePrinter(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Then you can use a loop to build four threads for each season, add them to a `List` and then use a parallel unordered stream to *`start()`* the (16) threads. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable[] seasons = { new MessagePrinter("Winter"),
            new MessagePrinter("Spring"), 
            new MessagePrinter("Summer"),
            new MessagePrinter("Autumn")
    };
    List<Thread> al = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Runnable r : seasons) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            al.add(new Thread(r));
        }
    }
    al.stream().unordered().parallel().forEach(Thread::start);
    for (Thread t : al) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which consistently produces an unpredictable ordering of results on my system. Sample run,

```
Summer
Summer
Winter
Summer
Summer
Autumn
Autumn
Winter
Winter
Spring
Winter
Spring
Spring
Spring
Autumn
Autumn
```

For a more extreme "messed-up" output, modify the `MessagePrinter.run()` method to `flush()` and `yield()` after every character. Like,

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(msg.charAt(i));
        System.out.flush();
        Thread.yield();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Sample output

```
SSuummerm
mer
Summer
Spring
Spring
SumWinmter
er
WiAutunmAutumn
tSprin
Ser
pringAutumng
n

AWinWitntuer
teumn
r
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted make demo for thread switching. So, 16 threads  with one string output cannot serve for this purpose. However, your second letter by letter `MessagePrinter::run()` worked. Thank you (+1)